# Render a Checkbox in Twig; Boolean expected error

Tags: symfony, checkbox, twig, silex

I'm trying to render a checkbox inside a form but got the next error:

> TransformationFailedException in Form.php line 1149: Unable to
>   transform value for property path "[active]": Expected a Boolean.

Yes, what I send is an integer 0 or 1, but twig get them as string and it has sense but I really can't find how to render the checkbox.

This is the controller:

```
    $form = $form->add('active', 'checkbox', array('label' => 'User active?','required' => false));
```

And this is the Twig side:

```
{{ form_widget(form.active, { attr: { 'class': 'form-control' }}) }}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your form add a model transformer as @Rinat suggested:

```
$form->add('active', 'checkbox', array('label' => 'User active?','required' => false));
$form->get('active')
     ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
         function ($activeAsString) {
             // transform the string to boolean
             return (bool)(int)$activeAsString;
         },
         function ($activeAsBoolean) {
             // transform the boolean to string
             return (string)(int)$activeAsBoolean;
         }
    ));
```

More details here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
  */

  protected $active = false;
```

to your domain model.

Comment: I don't have a model layer in this app. Doing the sql requests on the controller.

Comment: In this case may be take a look to CallbackTransformer and addViewTransformer